# best way to compare 2d int array to character?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a program that goes through an traverses a maze. I am stuck with my logic, I want to create a simple if statement to compare if the character below my current location is either a '#' (wall) or '.' (free space). I understand there isn't really a way to compare primitive types, but I am in need of help for a solution so I don't continue to stare at this for another hour. I thought about using the ASCII values but im not quite sure if that would work with a 2d int array. Anything helps. Thanks!

```
if(currentLcoation[row - 1][col] == '.') //Check Down
    {

        int newX = row-1;
        int newY = col;
        currentLocation[][] = currentLocation[row-1][col];
    }
```

EDIT:
Below is the maze I am traversing. I think I was unclear my intent. I want to compare to see if the coordinate I am currently at (which would be an int[row][col]) to the maze piece of either '#' or '.'

```
# # # # # # # # # # # #
# . . . # . . . . . . #
. . # . # . # # # # . #
# # # . # . . . . # . #
# . . . . # # # . # . .
# # # # . # . # . # . #
# . . # . # . # . # . #
# # . # . # . # . # . #
# . . . . . . . . # . #
# # # # # # . # # # . #
# . . . . . . # . . . #
# # # # # # # # # # # #
```

Comment: so your 2d int array holds ASCII values for various characters? Can we see an example of what the 2d int array looks like?

Comment: why not use a 2d char array instead if what you're storing is actually characters?

Comment: What makes you think you can't compare variables of different primitive types ?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Everything I have been reading has told me it is not good practice.. if there is a way to properly do it I am all ears.

Comment: @whaleberd, the reason I can't use a 2d char array is because my currentLocation has to represent integer coordinates of my location on the maze.

Comment: You want to compare an `int` with a `char` literal. Just do it, there is not particular "proper" way. `'#' == 35` is true. `'#' == 345901` is false. What exactly is the problem ?

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis, Lets say for example my currentLocation is row 3 col 2. My issue is how to I compare currentLocation[2][3] to a '.' character, if the array is of type int and not char.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get your problem. The code you posted is absolutely fine. Comparing two primetives is the most basic thing you can do and there is nothing bad about it.
You can compare `char`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `double` and `float` with `==` without any issues. `char` is internally handeled as number.  Even something like this is absolutely possible:

```
int i = 20 + 'A'; // Will be 85 as 'A' has the value 65 in ASCII
char c = 'A' + 2; // Will be 'C' or 67 (position of C in ASCII)
if(c == '#') { /* Do something */ } // Will execute if c is #
```

Did you mean you should not compare objects with `==`? Because this will not behave as you would expect.